# How to avoid system process using port 80?

Tags: tomcat, port

I changed my tomcat to use port 80, but log shows that this port has been used. So I want to know how to check which process is using port 80 and how to close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open CMD Command, type into command, and precess Enter:

```
netstat -ano | findstr ":80 "
```

you will get the process PID which is using port 80. And then type into

```
tasklist /fi "PID eq 4"
```

to find process name, and you could end this process at "Windows Task Manager" window.

[image]

If this process is "System", you could follow below steps to avoid "System" process using port 80.

Open CMD Command, type into command:

```
regedit
```

You will open Registry Editor window. Follows below directory, you will find a property named "Start".

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HTTP

Edit "Start" property, set value as 0, restart your computer, all problems resolved.

Comment: Thanks, the regedit solution worked! Can you please explain, though, what this setting does? It didn't stop the process from starting, it just doesn't use the ports I needed, anymore!